# How to hide a char within a pixel

Tags: java, pixel, steganography

I want to know how to alter the least significant bit(s) of a pixel to hide a character. The picture must remain visually unchanged but I would like to hide a message within it.

Comment: you can use them straightforward. Just store there bits of your data

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?
Starting point:

`bitmap.getPixel(0,0)....?`

Comment: `RGB rgb = bitmap.getPixel(0,0); rgb.R = rgb.R & 0xF7 | (data>>0) & 0x01; bitmap.setPixel(0,0, rgb);` It is not java, but show you idea. `0` in `(data>>0)` is index of bit hat you store.

Answer (score 0):

To make your problem more specific, let's say you are using a limited 7 bit character set and a plain RGB image (no alpha channel). You can split the character bits into groups of 2-2-3. Since blue is the channel that we see the least variation in, you can hide the 3 bit group in the blue channel. The following encoding/decoding examples will use a `Color` object to represent the RGB triplet, but the code should work for any equivalent representation:

**Encode**

Given a pixel that has some original value in the image and a character that you want to encode, replace it with

```
Color px; // The initial color in the image
char ch;  // The character to encode
...
// Store 2,2,3 bits of char in lowest bits of each pixel
// ... & ~0x3 clears the lowest two bits, the or assigns the replacement bits
Color newPx = new Color((px.getRed() & ~0x3) | ((ch & 0x60) >> 5),
                        (px.getGreen() & ~0x3) | ((ch & 0x18) >> 3),
                        (px.getBlue() & ~0x7) | (ch & 0x7));
```

**Decode**

```
Color px; // The image pixel with an encoded char
...
char ch = ((px.getRed() & 0x3) << 5) |
          ((px.getGreen() & 0x3) << 3) |
          (px.getBlue() & 0x7);
```

You have to know what part of the image contains the modified pixels for this to work. Also, make sure that your image data is compressed losslessly if you compress it at all.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you're going to need to define some convention for mapping your bits. We know that in an ARGB color definition for a pixel, 8 bits are assigned to each the Alpha, Red, Green, and Blue values. As you do not want to map your character entirely over one color, I suspect you will want to break it up evenly over each of the 4 values. You may also not want to edit the alpha, but you can adjust the code I provide fairly easily to accommodate that. Here is how an int is structured. Keep in mind each of the values of the components are 8 bits (range 0-255)

```
int color = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue
```

which is to say

```
int blue = color & 0xFF;
int green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

to hide the rightmost two bits of character c into a component (alpha, red, green, or blue) use

```
component = (component & 0xFC) | (c & 0x3);
```

repeat for each color and after each time shift c over two;

```
c >>= 2;
```

repackage as a color

```
 int color = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
```

to **decode**, break back into components

```
int blue = color & 0xFF;
int green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

then construct your character

```
 char c = ((alpha & 0x3) << 6) | ((red & 0x3) << 4) | ((green & 0x3) << 2) | (blue & 0x3);
```

this last bit assumes that when you were hiding the bits in the components you went in the order I listed ( alpha, red, green, blue). I hope this helps you with your work, presumable steganography.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.